# Probability of Winning [CARDS]

Tags: probability, discrete-mathematics

Assuming you're playing a card game with an opponent and his/her hand is showing a Jack and a nine and you have not seen your cards yet. To beat the opponent, you need a higher card with either 20 or 21. What is the probability of you winning the dealer with your current hand?

My thought process:

The only cards that can currently beat the dealer's hand are if you have 2 of the following combination of Ace, Jack, Queen, King and 10.

Given that a Jack is already shown, there are only 3 Jacks left and there are still 4 of Ace, Queen, King and 10.

Now, the probability of you having one of these cards as your first card is:

$$\frac{4}{50}+\frac{4}{50}+\frac{4}{50}+\frac{4}{50}+\frac{3}{50} = \frac{19}{50}$$

For the second card, the probability of having either Ace, Jack, Queen, King or 10 is:

(Assuming that we have either an Ace, Queen, King, or 10) 
$$\frac{4}{49}+\frac{4}{49}+\frac{4}{49}+\frac{3}{49}+\frac{3}{49} = \frac{18}{49}$$

Hence, probability of winning:

$$\frac{19}{50} \times \frac{18}{49} = 0.1396 \approx 13.96\% $$.

Would appreciate any help I can get on this!

EDIT1:
After getting feedback, I realized I had to calculate:

P(Don't draw two Aces) = $1$ - P(draw two Aces) = $1 - (\frac{4}{50}\times\frac{3}{49}) = 1- \frac{6}{1225} = \frac{1219}{1225}$

Also we had to calculate the probability we draw an Ace and a nine (since a nine was drawn by the opponent already, we have 3 Nine's left) = $\frac{4}{50} \times \frac{3}{49} = \frac{6}{1225}$

So, P(Winning) $= \frac{19}{50} \times \frac{18}{49} \times \frac{1219}{1225} \times \frac{6}{1225} = 6.8 \times 10^{-4} \approx 0.068\%$ (Looks wrong. Will think about it more deeply)

Comment: Sorry, are you asking for the probability that your current hand beats the dealer's?  Usually blackjack allows the player to draw cards.

Comment: Yes, the probability that my current hand beats the dealer's

Comment: Also, the second card of the dealer is opened *after* the players have theri first two cards ...

Comment: So, it's not blackjack.  You are just asking for the probability of holding a $20$ or $21$ given that your opponent holds $J,9$ yes?

Comment: And another point: Blackjack is played with six packs, so there are 23 (of originally 24) jacks left

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen I understand that is the case for a real game of blackjack. Assuming that in this case, the dealer shows both his cards before I show mine.

Comment: @lulu that's exactly right. I will edit my question

Comment: As the comments show, referring to Blackjack is very misleading here.  Blackjack is a game with specific rules, but you aren't interested in those rules at all.  Naturally, your readers are going to be confused.

Comment: to your question:  your methodology is fine, but you have to be clearer about what hands work.  you might have two Tens (of whatever sort), an Ace and a Ten, or an Ace and a nine.  Two Aces does not work.

Comment: @lulu ah yes, forgot about double Aces. hmm. ok!

Comment: And you forgot about Ace, nine .

Answer (score 0):

You have missed counting hands with an ace and a nine, which will beat the dealer as well.  You have counted hands with two aces, which will not beat the dealer.  Your approach is correct for the calculation you are doing, having two cards that are both either aces or ten counts.

Comment: thanks for your input!